# Get Percentage Matched property in percentage using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a use case which i need to input few list of properties which gives the result searches in mongodb which matches 90% property with all data.
For example:
I have data like

```
[{
    id: 1,
    properties: {
        'property1': 'value1',
        'property2': 'value2',
        'property3': 'value3',
        'property4': 'value4',
        'property5': 'value5'
    }
},
{
    id: 2,
    properties: {
        'property1': 'value1',
        'property2': 'value2',
        'property6': 'value6',
        'property7': 'value7',
        'property8': 'value8',
        'property9': 'value9'
    }
},
{
    id: 3,
    properties: {
        'property9': 'value9'
    }
}]
```

I would like to search for couple of property and i am looking for atleast 50% matches which is atleast 1 property should match with any of the two input
Input Query

```
find
{
    'property3', 'value3',
    'property7', 'value7'
}
```

From the above input, it matches with 2 data out of 3 data in DB. 
Is that possible write query with MongoDB?

Comment: Are you always going to search for a limited number of properties (or a constant 2 properties) or is that dynamic? If it's a static 2 like in your example you can simply write a query using $or...

Comment: definitely will be dynamic, it could be upto 30 property will be input.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: MongoDB 3.6.2 Community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that should get you going (you'll need a newer version of MongoDB, though, at least v3.4.4):

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: { // we add a helper field
        "propertiesAsArray": { // called "propertiesAsArray"
            $objectToArray: "$properties" // which will be the array representation of the "properties" field
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "matchRatio": { // the value we are looking for is...
            $divide: [ { // ...the ratio between...
                $size: { // ...the number of items...
                    $filter: {
                        "input": "$propertiesAsArray", // ...in our magic property array...
                        "as": "this",
                        "cond": { // ...that match any of our conditions...
                            $or: [
                                { $eq: [ "$$this", { "k": "property3", "v": "value3" } ] },
                                { $eq: [ "$$this", { "k": "property7", "v": "value7" } ] },
                                // ...of which we could have any number...
                            ] 
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }, 2 ] // ...and the number of properties in your query
        }
    }
}, {
    $facet: { // create two separate stages
        "totalNumberOfDocs": [{
            $count: "count" // one just calculates the total number of documents
        }],
        matchingDocs: [{ // and the second stage first filters out the non-matching documents
            $match: {
                "matchRatio": { $gte: 0.50 } // we only want documents with a match ratio >= 50%
            }
        }, {
            $count: "count" // and then counts the remaining ones
        }]
    }
}, {
    $project: { // final calculation of the ratio ("2 out of 3" in your example --> 66%)
        "percentage": {
            $divide: [
                { $arrayElemAt: [ "$matchingDocs.count", 0 ] },
                { $arrayElemAt: [ "$totalNumberOfDocs.count", 0 ] }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

If you are just looking for the matching documents and don't care too much about the 66% figure then this should work (untested because I'm on the way).

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: { // we add a helper field
        "propertiesAsArray": { // called "propertiesAsArray"
            $objectToArray: "$properties" // which will be the array representation of the "properties" field
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "matchRatio": { // the value we are looking for is...
            $divide: [ { // ...the ratio between...
                $size: { // ...the number of items...
                    $filter: {
                        "input": "$propertiesAsArray", // ...in our magic property array...
                        "as": "this",
                        "cond": { // ...that match any of our conditions...
                            $or: [
                                { $eq: [ "$$this", { "k": "property3", "v": "value3" } ] },
                                { $eq: [ "$$this", { "k": "property7", "v": "value7" } ] },
                                // ...of which we could have any number...
                            ] 
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }, 2 ] // ...and the number of properties in your query
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "matchRatio": { $gte: 0.50 } // we only want documents with a match ratio >= 50%
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for great help. it gives matching percentage. is possible to convert this to query to retrieve the matched records? Sorry, i'm really beginner in MongoDB

Comment: You'd need to tell me precisely which records in what shape you'd want.

Comment: From the example, it matched with 2 out of 3 records. So, your query given 66% percentage matched. It worked great. But, i want to know what are records it got matched for. In this example i can say, it matched for the document {id: 1, ....} and {id: 2, ....}

Comment: @dnickless: So, if we use this question in javascript array objects. how we do that?

Comment: @NguyenTungs: I don't understand what exactly you're asking. Kindly post a new question on SO and there will be responses!